# How to pass data from an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android

In my project I have to pass some data in a fragment activity . How do i do that ? I have tried like this :

```
String json_string = "s";
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowMapFragement.class);
intent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But it's not working properly. Please help me.

Comment: That is the correct way to pass data to another Activity using an intent. What about it is not working?

Comment: In my case I am passing data to a class that extends fragment . I think there is the problem . Please do help.

Comment: Oh so it's not a FragmentActivity? it's just a fragment? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please...I am stuck at that point .

Comment: Can you please post the complete code  to identify in which method or at what place you wrote that code? It seems you don't know how to instantiate any fragment.

Comment: I have written these lines of code in an activity that extedns AsyncTask  and the json data I need in another activity that extends Fragment :

Comment: @AbhishekDas I don't understand - an Activity cannot extend AsyncTask or Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to pass data from an Activity to a Fragment:

Create a static newInstance() method in the Fragment class:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String valueToPass) {
    MyFragment instance = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", valueToPass);
    instance.setArguments(args)
    return instance;
}
```

Pass the data from the Activity/Fragment to MyFragment like so:

```
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance("Hello World");
```

Then you can do this to retrieve the data (any time after Fragment.onCreate())

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       if (getArguments() != null) {
           String passedValue = getArguments().getString("key");
           // passedValue == "Hello World"
       }   
   }
```

Comment: where i have to write this portion ? in my Fragment class ?

Comment: Yes @AbhishekDas, in your Fragment class